# How to Fix NaN in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing an online Udemy Course on Backend Development and I can't figure out why I keep getting NaN on this code. I already have a working answer but I want to know if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

```js
function grader(array) {
  var total = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var total += total + array.length[i];
  }
  var avg = total / array.length;
  return Math.round(avg);
}
var scores = [98, 90, 89, 100, 100, 86, 94];
console.log(grader(scores));
```

I expect to have the program print out 94 but I keep getting NaN.

Comment: One problem is that your syntax is currently invalid. You cannot declare a variable and `+=` to it in the same statement. Only declare a variable *once* in the scope where you want it to be defined. Also, `array.length[i];` doesn't make any sense, the length of an array is a number, which doesn't have an `[i]`th index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the current `array[i]` to the `total`:

```js
function grader(array) {
  var total = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    total += array[i]; // changed from this - var total += total + array.length[i];
  }
  var avg = total / array.length;
  return Math.round(avg);
}
var scores = [98, 90, 89, 100, 100, 86, 94];
console.log(grader(scores));
```

An easier way would be to use reduce:

```js
function grader(array) {
  return Math.round(array.reduce((r, n) => r + n, 0) / array.length);
}
var scores = [98, 90, 89, 100, 100, 86, 94];
console.log(grader(scores));
```